# linux: time a command, redirect both stout and sterr to log file and show it in terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I know if I want to redirect both the output from the command and from "time" to a file I can do this:

```
(time python myscript.py) &> log.txt
```

What is the `tee` version of this, so everything will also show in the terminal? Another question is how can I also redirect the standard error from my command `python myscript.py` to `log.txt`

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to use a subshell, a group will be enough: `{ time python myscript.py; } &> log.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, using process substitutions (in Bash):

```
{ time python myscript.py; } &> >(tee log.txt)
```

I can see two benefits: the syntax is closer to your original command (and is hence, arguably, easier to remember): just replace your file by the process substitution. The other benefit is that the return code of your command will be available in the variable `$?` after your command has exited, unlike in the pipe case.

Observe that you don't have run your command in a subshell `(...)`, a command grouping with `{...}` is enough (mind the spaces around the curly brackets, and the trailing semi-colon).

This `tee`s stdout, stderr and the output of `time`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(time python myscript.py) 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

`2>&1` will redirect stderr to stdout before it is piped to `tee`.

Answer (score 0):

The `tee` equivalent would be (in `bash`)

```
(time python myscript.py) |&  tee log.txt
```

Comment: Can you point to documentation on this? I can't find any such, nor does it work in my bash shell.

Comment: @Politank-Z, check [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), look for "|& was added to Bash 4"

Comment: @Politank-Z: [here's the official documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines).